# Is there a multiplication transformation that will add the bottom row of a matrix to the top row?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given matrix 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
Is there a matrix $B$ such that:

$$
AB = \begin{bmatrix}
a+g & b+h & c+i \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$
Looking for a pattern, not an answer. I have tried fiddling with the identity but no combination has lead to success.

Answer (score 1):

By using elementary matrices, notice that if we left-multiply $A$ by the following matrix $C$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then we find that $CA = AB$. Thus, **if we assume that $A$ is invertible**, then we can take $B = A^{-1}CA$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a+g & b+h & c+i \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\ \end{bmatrix} = A +
\begin{bmatrix}
g & h & i \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

So, letting $B'=B-I$, it is equivalent to solve the equation: $$AB' = \begin{bmatrix}
g & h & i \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Let $\vec{u}, \vec{v}, \vec{w}$ be the rows of $A$.  The above equation says that $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ must be orthogonal to the columns of $B'$, and $\vec{u}$ must have inner product $g,h,i$ respectively with the columns of $B'$.

I claim that we can solve this equation exactly when either $\vec{w}=0$ or $\vec{u} \notin \operatorname{Span} \{\vec{v},\vec{w}\}$.  In particular, there is a solution when $A$ is invertible (but we knew that already).

If $\vec{u} \in \operatorname{Span} \{\vec{v},\vec{w}\}$, then $\vec{u}$ is also orthogonal to the columns of $B'$, i.e. $AB'=0$, so we must have $g=h=i=0$, or $\vec{w}=0$.

On the other hand, if $\vec{u} \notin \operatorname{Span} \{\vec{v},\vec{w}\}$, then there exists some vector $\vec{x}$ orthogonal to $\operatorname{Span} \{\vec{v},\vec{w}\}$ but not $\vec{u}$ (project $\vec{u}$ onto $\operatorname{Span} \{\vec{v},\vec{w}\}^\perp$).  Then we can let the columns of $B'$ be  $ \frac{g}{\vec{x}\cdot \vec{u}} \cdot\vec{x}$, $ \frac{h}{\vec{x}\cdot \vec{u}} \cdot\vec{x}$, $ \frac{i}{\vec{x}\cdot \vec{u}} \cdot\vec{x}$